# Добавление текста в QGraphicsScene в определенную точку

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Всем добрый вечер!

Снова возникла проблема при разработки Qt С++ приложения. На этот раз при работе с QGraphicsScene. Мне нужно на ней создать несколько кругов с порядковым номером внутри (в последствие это будут вершины графа). Круг отрисован, с этим проблем не возникло. Код:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QBrush whiteBrush(Qt::white);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(3);
    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(10);
    font.setBold(false);
    font.setFamily("Calibri");
    ellipse = scene->addEllipse(10, 10, 30, 30, blackPen, whiteBrush);
```

Далее в эту же точку пытаюсь добавить текст:

```
    QGraphicsTextItem *text = scene->addText("1");
    text->SetPos(10, 10);
```

На это компилятор выдаёт ошибку: 
**error: member access into incomplete type 'QGraphicsTextItem'**

В mainwindow.h прописывал:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rectangle;
    QGraphicsTextItem *text;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему :*(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен) Просто не прописал:

```
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
```

Теперь всё работает!